# Removing lines from list of files in terminal

Tags: sed, grep, command-line-interface, jq

I am trying to write up a command line interfaces that will removes a particular section / lines of codes within a list of json files. By the way, the json file are located within the sub-folders of the main directory

This is the code that I can come up with - `find -name "*.json" | xargs sed -i "map"` but some of the json files I had, its format is slightly different

So far I am seeing the following 2 formats within my list:

```
{
    "tags": {}, 
    "map": {
        "KPA": {
            "State": True, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "tags": {
        "type": [
            "char"
        ], 
        "dynamic": true
    }, 
    "unitmap": {
        "KPA01": {
           "State": True, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
```

and basically, I am trying to omit out the `map` section that it has, so that it will only display the `tags` section but the presence of commas and [] / {} are making it hard for me.

Will this be possible to do so in a command line interface?

Comment: Don't use `sed` to process JSON.  Use a tool that understands JSON, like http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ or a language like Ruby or Python which has modules for it.

Answer (score 1):

sed isn't very good for multiline matches.

You'll want to use [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead... it's, "like sed for JSON data".

Comment: `jq` is indeed a very new application to me... Is it also a command line thing?

Comment: indeed it is... just like sed but for json

Comment: Just wondering, for the case scenario that I am trying to achieve, will it be possible with jq, seeing that I have files of different formats as mentioned above in my post?

Comment: I am not sure if this is making sense, but I sort of finally found out the way to delete the object `map` - `jq 'del(.map)'` but say if I am running this command - `cat | find -name "*.json" | xargs jq 'del(.unitmap)'` while my terminal seems to be displaying the correct results, it isn't appending the results onto the file.. Did I did something wrong?

Comment: cat doesn't change files... it just streams them to standard output (usually the terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the end I still couldn't figure out using `jq` and instead upon finding some sources, I used a script to execute and perform the deletion

```
import sys
import json

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(inputfile,'r') as myfile:
    obj = json.loads(myfile.read().replace('True','true'))
    if "unitmap" in obj:
        del obj["unitmap"]
with open(inputfile,'w') as myfile:
    json.dump(obj,myfile,indent=4,separators=(',',': '))
```

Seems to work thus far but do comment in if there is a better way :)

Comment: By the way, this is slightly off, I can open another question if necessary. Currently I am working this script of mine in the root directory `find -name "*.json" -exec <script path> '{}' ';'` but I was wondering if it will be possible to perform the same action but it will only be targeting a few sub directories?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses **del**. If `input.json` contains

```
{
    "tags": {}, 
    "map": {
        "KPA": {
            "State": true, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
{
    "tags": {
        "type": [
            "char"
        ], 
        "dynamic": true
    }, 
    "unitmap": {
        "KPA01": {
            "State": true, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
```

invoking jq as

```
jq -M -c 'del(.map, .unitmap)' input.json
```

will produce the output

```
{"tags":{}}
{"tags":{"type":["char"],"dynamic":true}}
```